# Match a given set of keywords from mysql database

Tags: mysql, search

I have a column in my mysql database with set of keywords. (Specifically the lable data i'm getting from google vision api). Is there a easy way to match and return similar records when another set of lables given to the database.

In database:  "Bike vehicle transport light floor"
What i'm giving as search parameters : "light bike car green"

Approach i've taken currently: use the "LIKE" keyword with wildcard. Is there a better way to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: try to split keyword with spaces and then add separate where condition using LIKE and then add them with AND

Comment: that is what i'm currently doing
tags like %keyword1% or tags like %keyword2%
**tags is the column name
Is there a more smart way? i feel like this'll be troublesome when database grows larger..
thanks

Comment: Normalisation... and maybe some stemmer (porter stemmer for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution I propose, for which you'd have to use a STORED PROCEDURE is create a table of "`words`".

```
word_id INT() AUTOINCREMENT
word   VARCHAR(255)
```

Then split each word in the field and add it to the `words` table. If new add if old get the existing code for it. You then create a `used_words` table that links each record with the multiple words in contains.

```
record_id *(current record ID)*
word_id INT()
CONSTRAINT record_id *current_table(current record id)*
CONSTRAINT word_id words(word_id)
```

Finally, to compare a list against another, you see if every word you chose exist in the `used_words` table

```
select word_id from used_words
WHERE word_in not in (
   SELECT word_id FROM used_words
   WHERE record_id="$existing_id"
)
WHERE record_id="$new_entry_id"
```

If the result is NULL, then all the words exist. Otherwise, you have the list of different words.

The algorithm should work , but not a single SQL query

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a "complete" answer, and I'm not expecting it to be accepted as such.

Your topic of question is "Information Retrieval", and there are several good books on the subject (although they'll cover a far wider scope than your specific question - so YMMV unless you're particularly interested in the subject).

I'd read up on [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  I'd start by decoupling those keywords into a joining table, well indexed.

Also take a look a the subject of [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).  It's not a silver bullet, but it's core to getting the right results.  Some database engines can handle this for you - MySQL cannot (to my knowledge).  I'd recommend looking at the [Porter Stemmer](https://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/) for a good English example.  There are libraries for every major language.

Finally consider synonyms.  There's no easy way to handle these (in code); you'll need to build a database of them (better still, grab a [free one from online](http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/)).  You'll use this to "increase" the supplied keyword list, using related words.  ("Aeroplane" becomes "Aeroplane, Vehicle, Aircraft, Flying machine, Transport", etc).